# Android Ftp Download File Issue

Tags: android, file, ftp, download

I am really novice in android programming and I have an issue while downloading a file from my ftp server to sd card of my emulator. I have searched similar topics and tried to do every single recommendation and got no solution. I can download files without any problem. They are created in my SDcard with the exact name i want them to be bu they seem to be 0 bytes. I have necessary writing permisions in my manifest file for external storage and I use apache ftp commons utilities.

Here is my connecting code

```
public void ConnectFTP() {
    boolean status = false;
    try {
        mFtpClient = new FTPClient();
        mFtpClient.setConnectTimeout(10 * 1000);
        mFtpClient.connect(InetAddress.getByName(ip),21);
        status = mFtpClient.login(userName, pass);
        mFtpClient.enterLocalPassiveMode();
        Log.e("isFTPConnected", String.valueOf(status));
    } catch (SocketException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

and here is the code for downloading file from FTP

```
public void downloadFTP(String FTP_file, String SD_file,String folder) {
    ConnectFTP();
    File dir=new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+"/qaqc/" + folder);
    dir.mkdirs();
    try {
        mFtpClient.changeWorkingDirectory(folder);
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }

    BufferedOutputStream desFileStream = null;
    try {
        mFtpClient.enterLocalPassiveMode();
        if (!mFtpClient.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE)) {
            Log.e("binary", "Setting binary file type failed.");
        }
        desFileStream = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(
                Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+"/qaqc/"+folder+"/"+SD_file),
                8 * 1024);

        mFtpClient.retrieveFile("/"+FTP_file, desFileStream);
        desFileStream.flush();
        desFileStream.close();
        mFtpClient.logout();
        mFtpClient.disconnect();     
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Is there any solution or ideas to point me in the right direction? What am i doing wrong here?
Thank you.

Comment: Oh i made a silly mistake and thought it would be helpful for others in the same situation like me. I just removed slash ("/" +) character from my retrive method. It should be





mFtpClient.retrieveFile(FTP_file, desFileStream);






It is working well now and I can download my files from FTP.